# Counting points out of polygon using QGIS?

Tags: qgis-plugins, spatial-query

I would like to count the amount of points that are out of the polygon because I need to sum them.

I know how to count how many points are inside but in need to find how many there are outside.

Comment: Number of all points minus the ones inside?

Comment: Total points minus inside minus on the boundary,  technically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple method for counting only would be to use `select by location` in vector menu and select points inside that polygon. Then open the attribute table of your points layer and reverse selection. You can see the amount of selected points at the top of attribute table. 
If you need to unselect points inside more than one polygon you can use `add to current selection` instead of `create new selection` in `select by location` menu.

But of course you can **not** store that information in a (not existing) polygons attribute table as you could by using `count points inside polygon`.