# Points that fall outside a polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, point

I need to figure out how many points, and which ones (with labels) fall outside the boundary of a particular polygon in QGIS.

Answer (score 2):

Since you need to know wich points, with labels, fall outside the boundary of a particular polygon, It seems to me that your question is not a duplicate of [Count points out of polygon using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/263538). Equally that question has a good answer that I recommend you read, since you could achieve your goal also starting from the selection approach.

---

You can take advantage of the `distance( geometry a, geometry b)` function, to set a value to a new column in the point layer, from which you can then identify, count, and label the points that are outside a particular polygon.  **When a point is outside a polygon, the *distance* function returns a value greater than zero**.

Assuming you want to establish if each point is outside the single polygon feature that has the value *1* in the *id* field of the *polygons* layer.

Assuming also that you have created a column of string type to set the value *outside* if the point is outside that polygon, or an empty string if not.

You could populate that attribute with the following expression:

```
if( distance( $geometry, geometry( get_feature( 'polygons', 'id', '1'))) > 0, 'outside', '')
```

You can play a bit with this expression to get results more suited to your specific need.

Comment: I've created the string field but the command does not seem to work. I am new to this, would you please let me know how to write the command if the name of my polygon layer in "VDC" and the name of the point layer is "Households". I have created an empty string column named "string" in the polygon layer.

Comment: Hi @Sara, you can add an attribute to the points layer, wich tells if each point is outside the polygon or not. Also, you need to identify to which polygon of the VCD layer you want to compare the points. That polygon needs to have an "id" field for example. And you need to know to wich polygon id you want to compare the points. But the expression is for the points layer.

Comment: Then, you can do more analysis, like count all the points with the attribute 'outside', or label them. First try to achieve that attribute in the point layer.

Comment: I created the string attribute in the point layer and named it "outside". The VDC polygon layer only has 1 polygon. I merged them all because I need to know which households fall outside the VDC/Municipality boundary. So this polygon would have only one "id" which is named "VCODE" which I can see in the attribute table of the polygon.

Comment: Here is the expression which is not working: if( distance( $geometry, geometry( get_feature( 'VDC', 'VCODE', '47'))) > 0, 'outside', ''). The VCODE /id is 47 for the polygon. I selected the point layer from layers column, opened the python console and entered the expression in there.

Comment: Sow the polygon layer have a column named VCODE and have only one row? Enter some number, i.e. 1, for the single row and the VCODE column, and save it. And in the field calculator of the outside column in the points layer, you can populate with this expression: `if( distance( $geometry, geometry( get_feature( 'VDC', 'VCODE', '1'))) > 0, 'yes', 'no')`. You can search for the functions if(), distance(), $geometry(), geometry() and get_feature() to understand what are they doing.

Comment: No, this is not a python code! Is an expression for the field calculator.

Comment: Read this please: (https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#calculate-fields-values)

Comment: Ok I did what you instructed. I did not get an error but I could not click on update an existing field in the field calculator and had to create a new field. The expression does not have a problem but the new field is now populated with only "no"'s for all households when I can see that the household is outside the polygon.

Comment: I am seeing a message that says "This layer does not support adding new provider fields. You can only add virtual fields". Thanks so much for bearing with me!

Comment: Your points are on a CSV? If yes, no problem, use a virtual field. And use your expression:  `if( distance( $geometry, geometry( get_feature( 'VDC', 'VCODE', '47'))) > 0, 'outside', '')`, mine is for the polygon with a VCODE = 1, but yours is VCODE = 47.

Comment: Yes points are on a CSV. It worked! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Is there a way to find out by how many meters the household/point falls outside the boundary now?

Comment: That's good, I'm glad to hear that! You are welcome. Yes, in a real number field, with the expression: `distance( $geometry, geometry( get_feature( 'VDC', 'VCODE', '47')))`

Comment: I'm assuming that your layers have a projection system in meters (they are not EPSG: 4326). If not, export them to an appropriate reference system on which to perform measurements in meters.

Comment: I had to change it to CRS projection to initially merge the polygon features into one polygon. It is now is  EPSG:3410 (OTF). The new attribute is showing a distance of 0.0115949158916992 whereas if I use the ruler and draw a line from the point to the closest boundary I am getting 1280 m. Something is not adding up.

Comment: Maybe thats the project CRS, but not the layers CRS. Export your layers (right click on the layer, Save As) and make sure to define EPSG:3410 for the shapefiles.